# tMongoDBOutput - Configuring JSON tree

Tags: json, mongodb, talend

Trying to configure JSON tree for tMongoDBOutput. Only 1 element is getting created in subelement array. Can someone please give a example of configuring the JSON tree. Requirement is one document can have multiple nested sub documents. Medical_records can have multiple sub documents, but only 1 sub document is getting created now skipping the rest.
[image: JSON Tree configured]

Resulting JSON in MongoDB as follows

```
{
"first_name" : "testname",
"middle_name" : [],
"last_name" : "test",
"medical_records" : [ 
    {
        "dateofuploading" : "2016-09-29 12:49:21.5",
        "filename" : "demo.pdf",
        "isautogenerated" : "1",
        "recordid" : "123"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIw8V.png)If you want to have multiple sub documents in array,You need to use the group by operation in the advance settings for the element inside the array .